# Asp.Net How to get the string results of a regex instead of just one

Tags: asp.net, regex

Im trying to have a regex tester where the user writes a regex parameter such as [A-Z] into a textbox, for the user to test if the regex is good i wanted to show the results of is regex so i made to more textboxes where he can write a phrase to be tested.

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LblRegex" Text="Regex:">
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txbRegex"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:Label ID="LblRegexTester" runat="server" Text="Teste o seu Regex:">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txbRegexTest"></asp:TextBox>
                            </asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:Label ID="LblResultRegex" runat="server">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txbResultRegex"></asp:TextBox>
                            </asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnTest" OnClick="btnTest_Click" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


 protected void RegexMaker(string Regex, string RegexTestText)
    {
        char RegexResults;
        Regex rg = new Regex(Regex);

        MatchCollection MatchedRegex = rg.Matches(RegexTestText.ToString());


        for (int count = 0; count < MatchedRegex.Count; count++)
        {
            //txbResultRegex.Text = count.ToString();


            txbResultRegex.Text = MatchedRegex[count].Value.ToString();
        }


        


    }

    protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string regex = txbRegex.Text;
        string regexTestText = txbRegexTest.Text;
        RegexMaker(regex, regexTestText);
    }
```

The problem im encountering here is that it only results in one character.What can i do to show all the matches it gets.

Comment: The `txbResultRegex.Text = MatchedRegex[count].Value.ToString();` is re-writing the `Text` property each time. How do you want to display your results?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh i see, i wanted to display on the txbResultRegex, maybe just in a a line no fancy things just plain  and simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite `txbResultRegex.Text` property each time with a new match value in `txbResultRegex.Text = MatchedRegex[count].Value.ToString();`.

You need to get all the matches and display them, say, using `,` or some other delimiter. Here is an example:

```cs
protected void RegexMaker(string Pattern, string RegexTestText)
{
    var MatchedRegex = Regex.Matches(RegexTestText.ToString(), Pattern);
    txbResultRegex.Text = $"Count: {count.ToString()} Matches: {string.Join(", ", MatchedRegex.Cast<Match>().Select(x=>x.Value))}";
}
```